# Ubuntu One contacts not syncing?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, thunderbird

With the 11.10 update, I discovered an "Ubuntu One" address book in my Thunderbird address books. Exciting! But ... it doesn't seem to be syncing. I've got "Enable Contacts Sync" checked in Ubuntu One's control panel and I'm able to add addresses to the new "Ubuntu One" address book, but they don't seem to leave my laptop.

I don't see any way to troubleshoot this within Thunderbird or Ubuntuone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and it's probably not in Thunderbird, but in Evolution Data Server, which is currently used for this purpose. It is at least partially related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/desktopcouch/+bug/872639

Comment: It seems to have resolved itself, as of a recent update. Now if only I could sync Ubuntu One to Android.